# Azure sql database tls

Tags: azure-sql-database, tls1.2

How do I disable TLS versions prior to 1.2 on Azure SQL database.

I know that Azure SQL database always uses encrypted connections and supports TLS 1.2, but I want to disable previous versions of TLS.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: As of today, SQL Azure does support a model to enforce TLS 1.2+.  Announcement is here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/sqldb-minimal-tls-version/

Comment: Cunningham; Are there any plans to fix this?

Comment: yes.  however, i don't have a date that I can share with you at this time.  It is obviously something that we'd like to do ASAP and it is something we've done for SQL Server already.

Comment: Cunningham; Super. Thank you. Our auditors are really looking forward to this.

Comment: Was the option just updated? on my Azure SQL Database Server, I just noticed that "Firewalls and virtual networks" have a section called "Minimal TLS Version", which allows me to select ">1.0", ">1.1" and ">1.2".

Comment: yes :).  You got here before I could go update the answer for you.

Comment: Strange thing is, even after setting this to TLS 1.2, it still seems to permit connections using older protocol versions. For example, `openssl s_client -connect mydb.database.windows.net:1433 -tls1_1` - this shouldn't  negotiate a connection, but it *does*. Maybe this is some quirk of how SQL Server works, but it's got our pen testers in a bit of a fizz

Comment: The gateway to which you connect is shared and not all customers use TLS1.2+ only.  So, you may be seeing that behavior.  You didn't mention if the connection to your TLS 1.2+ DB was successful or not - please clarify.  (It should fail assuming the client command only allows 1.1 for your example)